# WSO2 Carbon ClassLoader seems to load the wrong OpenCMIS Authenticator

Tags: classloader, alfresco, wso2, opencmis

First the positive part:
I am trying to connect to Alfresco using OpenCMIS, and this works, when running the Java code directly :)

Now the negative:
However, when trying to run the Java code from WSO2 Carbon, there seems to be a classloader problem and the wrong Authenticator class gets loaded.

I am currently using the [OpenCMIS 0.10.0](http://archive.apache.org/dist/chemistry/opencmis/0.10.0/chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.10.0-with-dependencies.zip) version, although I've also tried with 0.11.0 and 0.12.0 (the most recent) versions.

This is the error in ws02carbon.log:

```
 ERROR -  Authentication provider does not implement AuthenticationProvider! {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver}
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication provider does not implement AuthenticationProvider!
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.CmisBindingImpl.<init   (CmisBindingImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.CmisBindingFactory.createCmisAtomPubBinding(CmisBindingFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.CmisBindingHelper.createAtomPubBinding(CmisBindingHelper.java:97)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.CmisBindingHelper.createBinding(CmisBindingHelper.java:55)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at nl.rem.test.cmis.CmisTestClient.test(CmisTestClient.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:178)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterServletAdaptor.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.jsservices.custom.ui.CustomUIServletFilter.doFilter(CustomUIServletFilter.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.statistics.webapp.RequestIntercepterValve.invoke(RequestIntercepterValve.java:43)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bam.webapp.stat.publisher.WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.invoke(WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code:

```
public class CmisTestClient {

    public static final String ALFRESCO_ATOMPUB_URL = "http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom";    
    private static final String ALFRESCO_USER = "admin";
    private static final String ALFRESCO_PASSWORD = "admin";


    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        test();
    }


    public static void test() {

        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();                                    

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();

        // User credentials.
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.USER, ALFRESCO_USER);
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, ALFRESCO_PASSWORD);

        // AtomPub Connection settings...
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, ALFRESCO_ATOMPUB_URL); 
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());              
        //parameters.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS, CmisBindingFactory.STANDARD_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER); // = the default
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true" );
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.COOKIES, "true" );

        // Alfresco only provides ONE repository.        
        Repository repository = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameters).get(0);

        Session session = repository.createSession();        
    }    

}
```

I am really lost how to fix it, I've tried (including restarting the webserver):

1. moving the OpenCMIS jars to: 
   -[WSO2 Carbon Home]\5.2.1\lib
   -[WSO2 Carbon Home]\5.2.1\repository\lib
   -[WSO2 Carbon Home]\5.2.1\repository\components\lib
   -[WSO2 Carbon Home]\5.2.1\repository\components\extensions
2. including the OpenCMIS jars directly in the .aar file, with  EnableChildFirstClassLoading=true (also tried with false)

Please help! It's not the first time there has been a problem when using third party libraries from within WSO2 Carbon and I'd like to understand what mistakes I am making :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a fix for the problem, though this solution is far from ideal:

Placing the jar files inside:

-`[WSO2 Carbon Home]\5.2.1\repository\deployment\server\lib`

**USING THE ADMIN CONSOLE** (vertical tab "Configure" on the left, and then "Repositories - Carbon" and "server - lib - +add dependencies")

By the way, thanks for the edit on the previous question Mardoz! :)